# Make jtab active on the meta so we can have a formatting sandbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jtab

Today [this question came up](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33814/would-any-alternatative-tuning-suit-this-chord-progression-song) where the OP wanted to use jtab in his post, but it wasn't rending even though **the website for jtab** showed it working. It took a lot of trial and error from me and the OP to actually get it in a good state as seen in the [edit history](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/33814/revisions) which for some reason had a problem with the Dsus2 chord and some spaceing.

A formatting sandbox on the meta would prevent someone having to edit their question multiple times on the main site due to a rendering error on our side and even more so since we can't render it in a preview yet.

Comment: [We now have a sandbox](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox). Please use it for testing out posting either jtab or abcjs.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having that problem in [Fighting against the F Chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44938/fighting-against-the-f-chord)

This is supposed to be rendering an F chord and a Bm7b5 chord as shown on http://jtab.tardate.com but no joy:

```
%1/X/1.X/4.2/3.2/2.1/X[F]
```

In the short term, if anyone can show me what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: They all display now. There was an extra slash in both. Double check the fingerings/notes are what you want on your post I think I screwed up the F chord.

Comment: @Dom I'm terribly sorry but I screwed it up again and I don't see any history on the deleted post so I can see how you fixed it again.

Comment: Now it shows.  And I have the history as well. Maddening.  Must have been a Chrome glitch.